# Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR] When running Xamarin.UITests on the new Android 10 OS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

There appears to be a console error every time a Xamarin UI test run on my Pixel with OS 10 on it. The error is as follows "Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]" The error does not seem to stop the application from running it more of a question as to why it's occurring and how to fix it.
Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we worked together!

Your Xamarin UITest might be trying to delete some system app using `pm uninstall`. But if it instead uses 
`pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.service` or `adb uninstall --user 0 com.android.service` (without opening adb shell), the command is issued as root. So without the extra tags, you should get the error.

To be safer, you can try to find the problematic system app and just disable it in the settings.

Comment: I think you might be right :)
You help me track down the issue I had code like this that was failing
' var eraseProcess = Process.Start(string.Format("/Users/{0}/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb", Username), "shell pm uninstall {app Name}");'
I need to make sure that I checked for an emulator if it is running and I used 'isEmulator()' code to make sure the above code only run on an emulator